# Two self signed CAs for frontend and backend local testing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Question:

How do I create two self signed certificates for a frontend running on localhost:3000 and a backend running on localhost:8080

Context:

Hi I am developing a web application with a React frontend and a Nodejs backend. I need to use https so I can test out if I can do something with cookies (not really important for the scope of this question). I have my frontend running on localhost:3000 and my backend on localhost:8080.

So far, I have created a self signed cert (at localhost) that is trusted by chrome for my frontend. However my frontend needs to send a POST request to my backend and get back cookie headers which I hope will work now that I am using https. However, when my frontend sends a POST request, the backend self signed cert that I created seems not to work (the common name I set was localhost:8080) it replies back with `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Are there any other solutions to go about getting https for the two applications so i can test locally? Containers? Any help would be useful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the same CA with the common name localhost for both the backend and frontend even though its on different ports. I am using this so I can set cookies in chrome with the flags secure and sameSite=None so that I can handle cookies in my auth flow.